# Silent the ringer and vibrate during call

Tags: android, telephonymanager, ring, android-vibration

Writing a program in which user can silent ringer and vibration without tapping power button for incoming call.

Below is the code i am trying

```
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) BoloApplication.getApplication().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Above code silent the ringer but phone still vibrate.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to suspend both ringing and vibration:

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: This is the official way: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT